# Console application execution arguments

Tags: c#, console-application, command-line-arguments

I have an application that the user can start with his many arguments.
If I'm not mistaken, I think I can get those execution arguments all over my application.

the application is console application.

tried to google it, but didn't found how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Arguments for application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623625/c-sharp-arguments-for-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* get them using [`Environment.CommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx) or [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx), but I would strongly advise against this. It will make your code harder to test. Instead, parse your command line arguments on start-up into a more semantically meaningful form, and then propagate the relevant options to any code which needs it, potentially through a Dependency Injection framework.

That way you'll end up making it much clearer which pieces of your code rely on which options, and you'll also be able to write unit tests for those classes without using any global state. All your command line parsing and validation will be in a single place, too.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Environment.CommandLine`, which gives you a straight string of the commmand line arguments or you can use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`, which gives you an array of the arguments. Beware that the first element in the array will be the name of the application.

Answer (score 2):

You could read them into a global variable inside main(), then use them throughout your app.

Answer (score 2):

`Environment.CommandLine` and [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs)

The last option is preferable because it gives you back a string array with every single argument passed on the command line. Remember, ther first one (index 0) is the executable file name